# Mac Book Pro Retina Failed to Connect External Monitor via HDMI port with Intel Iris

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I want to connect my MBP 2015 to my external monitor http://www.asus.com/Monitors/VS239H/ through HDMI port. I found out that by using AMD Radeon, my MBP's battery is draining fast and the fan is noisy. So, I try to use gfxCardStatus to use Intel Iris Only.

But, it just doesn't connect at all. The external monitor doesn't detect my MBP (it says HDMI No Signal). My MBP also doesn't detect my external monitor.

Why does it happen? And how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any kind of adapters to connect the monitor or is it straight HDMI to HDMI connection? I had troubles with non-apple adapters – the simply dind't worked for me...

You can make 2 things to diagnose the issue I can think of:

- boot into linux (make a usb from ubuntu with unetbootin)and check if it works in linux – if it does it's a software issue (i guess), meaning some kind of hack is necessary
- check your `system.log` by opening the Console.app or by tailing it in terminal with `tail -f /var/log/system.log`, also take a look if `sudo dmesg` got anything useful to say.

When you got the console or terminal open – just connect/disconnect the monitor and check if you get any kind of log activity from it, that should at least give you some idea if the hardware reacts on the display when **Intel HDxxxx** is used for graphics.

I would first check the syslog and then check the setup in Ubuntu 15.10, grab the latest Ubuntu iso file from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/wily-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Sadly, I use HDMI to HDMI connection.

Comment: still, check the log output for some hints when connecting/disconnecting

Comment: found anything in the logs when connecting/reconnecting?

Comment: haven;t had time to check the logs, been busy in projects. I hope I can check it in the weekend. I will post it here after I do that. Thanks :)

Comment: I have check it, see it here : https://gist.github.com/ismailsunni/b5d98e174e041caf3e17

I didn't get the log in first time, but I plug n un-plug the HDMI, then something is coming out. Not working still though.

Comment: Got it. Check out this thing: https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor
Install it, and see if it detects the monitor you are connecting through HDMI:
`/Applications/DisableMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/DisableMonitor --list`
Should give you a table like this one, with at least 1 item – if you utility sees your monitor try the disable/enable function.

Comment: Stupid question: did the ASUS screen worked with any different connection? So if you connect it and you switch to Intel HD it does not work, but with the AMD card it does? Just to be clear ;-)